# Hide buttons in Touch Bar depending on a condition

Tags: visual-studio-code, macbookpro-touch-bar

I just got a new MacBook Pro with a Touch Bar and I wanted to create an extension specific for Angular apps.
The purpose of the extension was to provide some buttons on the Touch Bar so the user can like, generate a component or rather launch the 'ng serve' command or something else.

My question here is : is it possible to hide some buttons on the Touch Bar depending on a condition, like if I'm on a Angular project or not ?

I have tried things but none of them worked.

Thank you for your time.